# How do I retrieve the properties of a photo taken on a digital camera using .NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, metadata, exif, photos

Preferably in VB.Net, but C# is fine, how can I access the extra properties added to a file by my digital camera, like `Date Picture Taken`, `Shutter Speed` or `Camera Model`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following [article](http://www.vsj.co.uk/dotnet/display.asp?id=649) should be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

I maintain a library that offers comprehensive support for extracting image metadata from a variety of file formats.

https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet

Answer (score 3):

When I built something similar I used this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/exifextractor.aspx) quite a bit. But basically you're looking for the EXIF data embedded in the image.

There are a number of great libraries to extract it for you, if you don't want to write it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the [`BitmapMetadata`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapmetadata.aspx) class in the [`System.Windows.Media.Imaging`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.aspx) namespace.

There is a [`BitmapMetadata` sample that can be downloaded from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771454.aspx).