# How can I implement lazy bitmap loading?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, lazy-evaluation

I want to write a function that will get as input string **fileName** and return an **ImageDrawing** object.
I don't want to load the Bitmap from the disk in this function. Instead, I want to have some kind of lazy evaluation.
In order to find out the dimensions, I use the **Bitmap** class.

Currently I have this code:

```
    public static ImageDrawing LoadImage(string fileName)
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap b = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(fileName);
        System.Drawing.Size s = b.Size ;
        System.Windows.Media.ImageDrawing im = new System.Windows.Media.ImageDrawing();
        im.Rect = new System.Windows.Rect(0, 0, s.Width, s.Height);
        im.ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Absolute));
        return im;            
    }
```

1. Is the call to **System.Drawing.Bitmap** constructor lazy?
2. Is the call to **.Size** lazy?
3. Is the **BitmapImage** constructor lazy?
4. Is there any other way that I can implement it to be fully lazy?

---

Edit: 
There are many good answers that might be helpful to the community - to use **Lazy** class and to open it with a **Task**.
Nevertheless, I want to put this **ImageDrawing** inside a **DrawingGroup** and serialize afterwards, so **Lazy** as well as **Task** is not an option for me.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552467/how-do-i-reliably-get-an-image-dimensions-in-net-without-loading-the-image

Answer (score 4):

The constructor of the `Bitmap`class is not lazy but you can use the `Lazy<T>` class which is made for exactly that purpose:

```
public static Lazy<ImageDrawing> LoadImage(string fileName)
{
    return new Lazy<ImageDrawing>(() => {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap b = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(fileName);
        System.Drawing.Size s = b.Size;
        System.Windows.Media.ImageDrawing im = new System.Windows.Media.ImageDrawing();
        im.Rect = new System.Windows.Rect(0, 0, s.Width, s.Height);
        im.ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(fileName,     UriKind.Absolute));
        return im;
    });
}
```

From the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286.aspx):

> Although you can write your own code to perform lazy initialization, we recommend that you use Lazy instead. Lazy and its related types also support thread-safety and provide a consistent exception propagation policy.

Comment: (+1) For the helpful answer for the community. But it is not good for me specifically, I have updated my question - please check it out

Comment: When I try to serialize an instance of with this code..

`    var img = LoadImage("C:\\Windows\\Account.png");
    Stream stream = File.Open("Serialized.osl", FileMode.Create);
    BinaryFormatter bformatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    bformatter.Serialize(stream, img);
    stream.Close();
`
... I get the error message that 'System.Windows.Media.ImageDrawing' is not serializable. That's the same message you would get without the `Lazy` wrapper... How are you trying to serialize this thing anyway?

Comment: You have to pass in the Value property to the serializer: `System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(img.Value);`

Comment: But then it would not be lazy. img.Value will initialize.

Comment: In the moment you serialize, it will always be initialized :) Maybe you can tell us what you are trying to achieve here is a broader context?

Comment: It could have been serialized only with the relevant properties - height, width, fileName. Not opening the Bitmap from disk

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use Timer within your class and download your image in a "lazy" manner. Also you can try to implement Task of [MS TPL](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCQQFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx&ei=8mMMT63BCYaxgwfF3uyzBw&usg=AFQjCNGjTfP3C9wE1gKSbCEzZlCOZrAYkA) to do it as well inside of the Timer tick event.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it might be useful to somebody else - so (+1). For me it is not useful because I need to serialize the BitmapImage, and I don't want to serialize Tasks

Comment: I see... Well.. Do it then without a Task. But you can try to re-view your class and implement all things you need. In fact the class which is going to do some job should be a different one. And keep your data/images in class which doesn't have any transformation methods. I mean try to split the data and methods to manipulate it into 2 diff. classes.