# how to get the properties of a bitmap?

Tags: c#

How would I get the copyright date from a bitmap?

```
private void toolStripMenuItemLoadImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        ofd.Title = "Load Image";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            firstLoaded = new Bitmap(ofd.FileName);
            String details = //Grab the copyright date of the image here; 
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }
    isLoaded = true;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by Copyright date?

Comment: There's no space in the bitmap file format for such a thing.

Comment: i mean getting things like the date the image was created, last modified etc... is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking to get the system-provided details, then you should look into shell functions (shell32.dll). Check out this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c).

Basically, it's not saved in the bitmap itself, rather in the system. It contains like specified rating, user, details etc.

Answer (score 0):

Load the image into a bitmap object and access the exif data. See the second answer of this question: [How to get the EXIF data from a file using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649/how-to-get-the-exif-data-from-a-file-using-c-sharp)

About access Time and co use the FileInfo class. See also the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastaccesstime.aspx

Comment: I didn't think EXIF data was stored in windows bitmap files.

Comment: BMP files have AFIK no copyright data. Btw also if it's uncommon PNG supports EXIF too.