# Place detection in images on windows phone

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm woking now on my senior project, it about identify the places through pictures on windows phone 8 platform.

Any libraries or algorithms could help me ?

Answer (score 0):

if the data is embedded in the image: see [How to get the EXIF data from a file using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649/how-to-get-the-exif-data-from-a-file-using-c-sharp)

if not: Then perhaps a google api may help, I don't know Google's APIs but here is an article which may give you some idea for what to search for: http://www.labnol.org/internet/find-picture-location/21273/

Comment: i want something about imagesprocces .. because maybe there is places in the same place but each one in different direction.