# Is it possible to Extract Metadata from a file using c# in a winforms Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, metadata, computer-forensics

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas of how to extract Metadata from files in C#, I am wanting to create an application where the user has upload a file e.g a PDF or JPEG file and it will extract all the Metadata from the file and output it? Some of the metadata will include:

- Author
- Date Created
- Date Modified
- File Size

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869388/how-to-read-extended-file-properties-file-metadata

I think you will find your answer here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read extended file properties / file metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869388/how-to-read-extended-file-properties-file-metadata)

Answer (score 3):

There is a library called [TagLib-Sharp](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp) for reading and writing metadata in files
It works for Video/Audio/Image files but it does not support PDF files.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look!