# How to open a jpg file with your application?

Tags: c#, windows, registry, mouseclick-event

I am developing an application and I need to read the EXIF details of JPG file. 
I am able to do so with an OpenFileDialog button but, I want it to be so that a user can open a JPG file with my application (right click>Open with) and I could get the path of the JPG file in string.

I just want to know how to get the path of the file on which the user right clicked ad selected open with "My Application"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the EXIF data from a file using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649/how-to-get-the-exif-data-from-a-file-using-c-sharp)

Comment: i have followed the given link and have been able to get the exif data, now i want to open a jpg with the app by using the open with button in the right click menu.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, that's not what the OP is asking

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to get the EXIF data already and just want users to be able to right-click a JPG file > Open with > Select your application and then get the filename they're trying to open, you can do this:

```
private void testButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] cmdLineArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    string jpgFilenameToOpen = "None";

    if (cmdLineArgs.Length > 1)
    {
       jpgFilenameToOpen = cmdLineArgs[1];
    }

    YourGetEXIFDetailsMethod(jpgFilenameToOpen);
}
```

The `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` returns an array with all command line arguments that was passed to your application on load.  Normally, if they just pass a filename, it should be the 2nd item in the array.

You can also loop through the arguments if needed by doing this:

```
foreach (var arg in cmdLineArgs)
{
    MessageBox.Show(arg.ToString());
}
```

**Edit:**

I just realized I'm not sure if you need to accept only one JPG filename at a time or if you need to accept multiple JPG files at once.  If it's the latter, here's some updated code that can loop through all the command-line arguments and do something with only JPG/JPEG files:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] cmdLineArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    List<string> jpgFilenamesToAnalyze = new List<string>();

    foreach (var arg in cmdLineArgs)
    {
        if (arg.Contains(".jpg") || arg.Contains(".jpeg"))
        {
            jpgFilenamesToAnalyze.Add(arg);
        }
    }

    if (jpgFilenamesToAnalyze.Count > 0)
    {
        StringBuilder sbJPGFiles = new StringBuilder();
        sbJPGFiles.AppendLine("Found " + jpgFilenamesToAnalyze.Count + " images to analyze:\n\nFiles:");

        foreach (var jpgFilename in jpgFilenamesToAnalyze)
        {
            // YourGetEXIFDataMethod(jpgFilename)
            sbJPGFiles.AppendLine(jpgFilename);
        }

        MessageBox.Show(sbJPGFiles.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No images found to analyze");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your application for the JPG file extension in the Registry as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144175(v=vs.85).aspx