# Ignore EXIF Orientation Tag from-TagsFromFile argument

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, exif, exiftool

I'm processing some images.Before processing I realign the image based on the orientation tag, process it and save it.After this process I copy all exif data using `exiftool`

```
 using (StreamWriter writer = new FileInfo(exifcommandpath + "exiftoolcommands.txt").AppendText())
 {

 writer.WriteLine("-TagsFromFile");
 writer.WriteLine(cpath);
 writer.WriteLine("--thumbnailimage");
 writer.WriteLine(outdir + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(cpath) + ext);
 writer.WriteLine("-overwrite_original");
 if (counter != Filelist.Count)
 {
 writer.WriteLine("-execute");
 }
 else
 {
 writer.WriteLine("-stay_open");
 writer.WriteLine("False");
 }
 }
```

But this produces wrongly oriented image.How can I selectively ignore the EXIF Orientation tag while copying?
Please advice..

Comment: Are you trying to run a program with arguments? Using the `Process` class with `ProcessStartInfo` for the arguments might be simpler for that. Overall though, I'd recommend [extracting the metadata programmatically yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649/how-to-get-the-exif-data-from-a-file-using-c-sharp) rather than using an external tool.

Comment: @Nyerguds Yes,I'm using an external tool  'exiftool' Arguments are written into a text file, which is read by the tool running in background.

Comment: Isn't your problem just that you first rotate the image, and then re-add the tags that tell viewers to apply rotation to the image? That would apply it twice when viewed.

Comment: @Nyerguds Yes.... Right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is the exact same way already in your code to avoid copying `ThumbnailImage`, two hyphens in front of the tag you don't want to copy `--Orientation`.

See [--TAG](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#TAG1) in the exiftool docs.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.The code was written some time back, did not remember why i used the `thumbnail` tag. Thanks :)

Comment: Since you're rotating the image, you would otherwise be copying an unrotated thumbnail, which would probably affect the display of software that would use the thumbnail.