# How to clear all metadata of a copy of an image file?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, metadata

I have a bunch of image files of the following types: bmp, jpg, gif, tif, and png.

What I want to do is make an exact copy of these files, but remove all the metadata in the copies to include everything under Description, Origin, Image, Camera, and Advanced photo (I believe those are the typical fields included, at least for tifs).

What I tried so far:
Simply creating a new Bitmap from the original image and writing it out to the copy DOES remove all the metadata:

```
using (var originalImage = Image.FromFile(filePath))
{
    using (Bitmap copyBitmap = new Bitmap(originalImage))
    {
        // Draw the original image onto the new bitmap
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(copyBitmap))
        {
            graphics.DrawImage(originalImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, copyBitmap.Width, copyBitmap.Height));
        }

        // Save the copy without metadata
        copyBitmap.Save(outputFileName);
    }
}
```

However, the size and vertical/horizontal resolution are different than the original. Also gifs are no longer animated.

I can of course use System.IO.File.Copy(originalImagePath, copyImagePath) to do the copying, but I don't see a way to strip the metadata from the copy files.

Comment: You'll probably need a TIFF library and or an EXIF library. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649/how-to-get-the-exif-data-from-a-file-using-c-sharp

Comment: So there's really no way to just clear out the data of a file? Seems weird since we can go into windows explorer, right click a file, and modify any of the fields very easily.

Comment: Oh, there's a way to do it, just not with straightforward `System.Drawing` methods (I don't think). And, I suspect that handling TIFF metadata is different from handling the EXIF metadata in a JPEG. Go hunting for some library or NuGet package

Comment: One minor thing.  You don't need to worry about BMAP images.  They cannot contain any embedded metadata.

Comment: `bitmap.Save(filename)`, without a type argument, will always save as png, by the way. As for the resolution, there's a SetResolution function for that.

Comment: Also note, this method will not retain the pixel format of the original image. All resulting images will be 32bpp ARGB.